# How do I get SQL LOAD DATA from CSV to honour the column type when loading?

Tags: sql, mysql, jdbc, load-data-infile, sqlexception

I am loading a CSV file into MySQL (5.1) using `CREATE TABLE` and `LOAD DATA`.  I have a number of columns which are textual types (categories) but contain numerical values.  When I create the table I assign these columns as `VARCHAR(254)` but the JDBC driver throws a SQLException "Data truncated for column AgeGroup at row 1".

My data looks like this:

```
ID,AgeGroup
xxx,4
xxy,3
xyx,6
...
```

My create table statement looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE abc(ID VARCHAR(254), AgeGroup VARCHAR(254))
```

My load statement looks like this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE \myfile.csv\ INTO TABLE abc FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

I am guessing that it is a type conversion issue because AgeGroup is a textual database column but I am sticking what appear to be numbers in it.

How do I - can I - force the `LOAD DATA` command to honour the datatype of the column and convert the contents of the file?

I'm using the official MySQL JDBC Driver.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that this doesn't work. I mean, I would expect this behaviour when sticking string values in numeric columns - not the otherway around.

Anyway, you can use an extension of the `LOAD DATA` syntax introduced in v5.0 to compute arbitrary expressions from your raw data:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE \myfile.csv\ 
INTO TABLE abc 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(@ID, @AgeGroup)
SET ID = @ID
,   AgeGroup = CAST(@AgeGroup AS UNSIGNED)
```

(see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html